# SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}

Tags: php, json

I am using jquery ajax call

```
var data="name"+get_name;
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"php/getAllInfo.php",
            data:data,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                var allDetails=data;
                console.log(allDetails);
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             console.log(errorThrown);
            },
             complete: function(){

            }
        });
```

php

```
$name = trim($_GET['name']);

$mysql_resultset = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT dod.deviceId, drs.cpuUtilization FROM device_owner_details dod, device_realtime_stats drs WHERE  dod.name = '$name' AND drs.deviceId= dod.deviceId ");

$rows_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysql_resultset);

$all_details = array('deviceId'=> $rows_data['deviceId'], 'cpuUtilization' => $rows_data['cpuUtilization']);

$response = json_encode($all_details);
echo $response;
```

mysqli statement is correct.but it gives syntax error, what is error in coding. Here cpuUtilization value is NULL

I want information like  { deviceId:'idvalue', cpuUtilization:'value'}

Comment: What does `var_dump($response)` output? Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I guess what you want is to fix your ajax data from "data:data," to "data: {name: get_name},".

Answer (score 0):

`Edit var data="name"+get_name;` to `var data="name="+get_name;`

Check your Response, If response is not in json or json is not valid then error was occuring

Comment: What's the difference?